# Evitar que ingresen a una pagina en mi web completando la URL

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de bloquear el acceso a una pagina modificando la URL. Algo asi:
Supongamos que esta la URL : mipaginaweb.com/bienvenido y si colocamos mipaginaweb.com/bienvenido/pagina entra a "pagina" pero yo no quiero que hagan eso sin antes haber presionado un botón en la pagina "bienvenido" por ejemplo.
Espero haberme explicado bien.
¿Existe alguna forma de bloquear ese acceso?

Comment: Que has investigado o intentado?

Comment: Si se puede con sesiones.

Comment: Asi como ha dicho @Bicho lo mejor es bloquear ese acceso por sesiones, desde PHP por ejemplo existen las funciones `session_start` y `session_end` ademas de la variable `$_SESSION`, la cual almacena los datos de la sesion iniciada por el usuario, solo es cuestion de saber usar estos 3 conceptos de PHP.